# Как можно ограничить текст в одной строке?

Tags: html, css, css3

Мне нужно сделать так, что бы  максимум в строке было 20 символов, потом идет перенос строки. Вот, например

```
<td colspan="3" class="user_text" style="word-wrap: break-word">
  {$item.review|strip_tags|truncate:500}
</td>
```

Сейчас она использует максимум. Width не работает. Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант использовать единицу измерения `ch` [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

> This unit represents the width, or more precisely the advance measure,
>   of the glyph '0' (zero, the Unicode character U+0030) in the element's
>   font

```css
div {  
  max-width: 20ch;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt rem odit quis quaerat. In dolorem praesentium velit ea esse consequuntur cum fugit sequi voluptas ut possimus voluptatibus deserunt nisi eveniet!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
  adipisicing elit. Dolorem voluptates vel dolorum autem ex repudiandae iste quasi. Minima explicabo qui necessitatibus porro nih</div>
```

Comment: с td работает ? Я попробовал - одно и тоже

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w3g0bc3t/

Comment: Очень странно. У меня все еще не работает.... буду разбираться